# How to set a VPageBreak between two specific columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I programmed a little tool in VBA which generates a sheet with some statistics on it.
I want to automatically have a printable worksheet, so I set the VPageBreak like this:

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1  
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

At first this worked just fine. But the content of this generated worksheet is based on data in another worksheet and when this data changed, the DragOff-Command threw an error.
The error occured because the VPageBreak is now automatically set at a place, where the Dragoff is not possible.

I need reliable code, not depending on the origin-data...
Is there a way to say "I want this VPageBreak after column E"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, try this ...

```
Sub SetPageBreaks()
Dim MySh As Worksheet

    Set MySh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MySh.VPageBreaks.Add MySh.[E1]
    MySh.VPageBreaks.Add MySh.[J1]

    MySh.HPageBreaks.Add MySh.[A5]
    MySh.HPageBreaks.Add MySh.[A10]

    ' removing breaks

    ' note ... page breaks are only counted and accessible as objects
    ' when they intersect with a Print range
    MySh.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:J10"
    MySh.HPageBreaks(1).Delete

End Sub
```

This adds vertical page seperations before columns E and J. No need to make VBA switch into PageBreakView, just set the VPageBreaks property.

You guessed it, ther's also a HPageBreak property for the Worksheet object ...

[further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193371(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thank you that is working but then my problem is that i still have VPageBreak(1) in the wrong position. I've tried VPageBreak(1).Delete but it generates an error. If I set VPageBreak(1).Location nothing happens at all. :(

Comment: But how? neither .Location nor .Dragoff xlToLeft, 1 show any effect on the VPageBreak.

Comment: edited answer ... make sure you have a Print Range defined which intersects the page breaks

Comment: Oh this is good know^^ Thanks for your help I got it working now