# Print range for each page

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change printed area per each page?

What I want to do: Manually in "page break preview" I can relocate line between pages, that redefine for me area per page. I want to do it from vba code. Is it possible?

My case: I have tables in excel, that created by code, that's mean number of lines in these tables can be different. I want to have the whole table in one page, not divided like I have now, for that reason I will check the end of the tables, and want to relocate end of the pages to these rows, in loop for all tables & pages.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: It's possible, look into `Worksheet.PageSetup`; note that the `PageSetup` & page breaks API is rather flaky, so you'll want to be in page break previous mode to manipulate page breaks. Got any code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find how can I implement Worksheet.PageSetup but I found VPageBreaks, I will try to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719060/how-to-set-a-vpagebreak-between-two-specific-columns
or this:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/533862-vba-hpagebreaks-location.html
Thank you @MathieuGuindon !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I found what I need. If somebody is interested this is the main idea:

```
Sub SetPageBrake()

    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
    Worksheets(1).ResetAllPageBreaks
    ActiveWorkbook.PageSetup.PrintArea = 'Put here some range

With 'worksheet
    Set .HPageBreaks(1).Location = .Range("A40") 'The page break will be above the cell
    Set .HPageBreaks(2).Location = .Range("A98")
End With

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```

Thank's for all the people who tried to help. Shame to people who put minus for my reputation without any clue even where to search an answer.